# Get all groups and roles for current user from LDAP

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I'm trying to get all groups and roles for current user from LDAP.
Here is my App.
If user logged in I need to get its roles and groups

I searched many post, but didnt found the answer

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    String searchbase = "dc=springframework,dc=org";

    Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<>();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:8389");
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org");
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "bobspassword");

    // trying to connect LDAP server
    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(environment, null);
    System.out.println("Connected!");

    SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
    String[] attributes = {"cn","ou"}; 
    controls.setReturningAttributes(attributes); 
    controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE); 
    NamingEnumeration<?> answer = ctx.search(searchbase, "(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames))", controls); 

    while(answer.hasMore()) { 
        SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult) answer.next(); 
        Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes(); 
        String groupsCN = attrs.get("cn").toString(); 
        String groupsOU = attrs.get("ou").toString();

        String [] groupname = groupsCN.split(":"); 
        String userGroup = groupname[1]; 
        System.out.println(attrs.get("cn")); 

        String [] groupnameOU = groupsOU.split(":"); 
        String userGroupOU = groupnameOU[1]; 
        System.out.println(attrs.get("ou"));
    } 
    System.out.println("Listed!");
    ctx.close();
    System.exit(1);             
}
```

and My LDAP server. It is a embedded LDAP server in Spring Boot

```
dn: dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: springframework

dn: ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: subgroups

dn: ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Ben Alex
sn: Alex
uid: ben
userPassword: password

dn: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Bob Hamilton
sn: Hamilton
uid: bob
userPassword: bobspassword

dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: developers
ou: developer
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=managers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: managers
ou: manager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=submanagers,ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: submanagers
ou: submanager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
```

I need to get roles and groups for user. Now I get all groups and roles. Somthing wrong in filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filter `"(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames))"` is just requesting all groups.
If you need the groups for a user (Ben), you want to filter the groups when the user is a member: `"(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org))"`